# Larvel Custom Validation Rule With Message Is Not Returning The Correct Error Message

Tags: php, laravel

I've written a custom validation class as such:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class PostValidationRule implements Rule
{
    protected $allowedTypes = ['text', 'image', 'video', 'link'];

    protected $_message = 'There was an error in creating the post.';

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $type = request()->input('type');

        if (!in_array($type, $this->allowedTypes)) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($type === 'text') {
            return !empty(request()->input('title')) && !empty(request()->input('content'));
        }
    
        if ($type === 'link') {
            return !empty(request()->input('title')) && !empty(request()->input('url')) && filter_var(request()->input('url'), FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false;
        }

        if ($type === 'image') {
            
            return !empty(request()->input('title')) && request()->hasFile('file') && request()->file('file')->isValid() && str_starts_with(request()->file('file')->getMimeType(), 'image/');
        }

        if ($type === 'video') {

            return !empty(request()->input('title')) && request()->hasFile('file') && request()->file('file')->isValid() && str_starts_with(request()->file('file')->getMimeType(), 'video/');
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return $this->_message;
    }

    
}
```

The custom rule is registered as a provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Rules\PostValidationRule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class CustomValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {   

        Validator::extend('post_validation', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
            return (new PostValidationRule)->passes($attribute, $value);
        });
    }
}
```

I am passing the following into Validation::make();

```
$data = [//some data froma for,]

$rules = array(
        'title' => 'required|string|min:0|max:255',
        'content' => 'required_if:type,text',
        'url' => 'required_if:type,link|url|nullable',
        'user_id' => 'required|uuid',
        'parent_id' => 'uuid|nullable',
        'type' => 'required|in:text,image,video,link',
        'file' => 'required_if:type,image,video|post_validation',
        'file.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg,mp4,mov,avi,ogg,mv4,flv',
    );
    enter code here

$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

print_r(validator->errors());
```

When I call the function to get the errors, the error message that is returned is 'validation.post_validation' and not the message defined in the message function. How do I return the message set in the message function?

Comment: How complicated can you make it? Ever heard of a FormRequest? There you go, and it has default messages function where you can act on that translation string you showed in your original question